# PrimeNG Datatable click to select/deselect rows

Tags: angular, primeng

When using the PrimeNG datatable module in my Angular app I have to hold ctrl/shift to multiselect rows. If ctrl/shift is not held then the selection is lost.  Is there a way to multiselect/deselect using a single click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out i just need to read the documentation more thoroughly.  For anyone else you need to set `[metaKeySelection]="false"`